# Configure diagnostic setting for Azure sql database via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to set diagnostic settings for my Azure sql database via ARM template, However the diagnostic part (nested under **database** resource) is failing because the type 'providers/diagnosticsetting' is invalid.

Error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 4:56:26 AM - Resource providers/diagnosticSettings 'monitor' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceNamespace",
    "message": "The resource namespace 'providers' is invalid."
  }
}'
```

ARM Template snippet:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "databases",
          "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
          "name": "[parameters('sqlDBName')]",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "sku": {
            "name": "Standard",
            "tier": "Standard"
          },
          "properties": {
            "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', concat(parameters('serverName')))]"
          ],
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "transparentDataEncryption",
              "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
              "name": "current",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('sqlDBName')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "status": "Enabled"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
              "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
              "name": "monitor",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('sqlDBName')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceIdForGlobalDiagnosticSetting')]",
                "logs": [

                ],
                "metrics": [

                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "vulnerabilityAssessments",
              "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
              "name": "default",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('sqlDBName')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "storageContainerPath": "[parameters('storageContainerPathForVulnerabilityAssesment')]",
                "storageAccountAccessKey": "[parameters('storageAccountAccessKeyForVulnerabilityAssesment')]",
                "recurringScans": {
                  "isEnabled": true,
                  "emailSubscriptionAdmins": false,
                  "emails": []
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/AllowAzureIPs')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/ActiveDirectory')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
        "login": "[parameters('azureActiveDirectoryAdminLogin')]",
        "sid": "[parameters('azureActiveDirectoryAdminSid')]",
        "tenantId": "[parameters('azureActiveDirectoryAdminTenantId')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/securityAlertPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "state": "Enabled",
        "emailAccountAdmins": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "isDevopsAuditEnabled": false,
        "retentionDays": 0,
        "auditActionsAndGroups": [
          "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
          "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
          "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP"
        ],
        "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
        "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": false,
        "state": "Enabled",
        "storageEndpoint": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('centralMonitoringResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').PrimaryEndpoints.Blob]",
        "storageAccountAccessKey": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccountAccessKey')]",
        "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccountSubscriptionId')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/securityAlertPolicies/Default')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "storageContainerPath": "[parameters('storageContainerPathForVulnerabilityAssesment')]",
        "storageAccountAccessKey": "[parameters('storageAccountAccessKeyForVulnerabilityAssesment')]",
        "recurringScans": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "emailSubscriptionAdmins": false,
          "emails": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/encryptionProtector",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/current')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "kind": "servicemanaged",
      "properties": {
        "serverKeyName": "ServiceManaged",
        "serverKeyType": "ServiceManaged",
        "autoRotationEnabled": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/connectionPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/ConnectionPolicies')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "connectionType": "[parameters('connectionType')]"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please try to update `"name": "monitor"` as `"name": "microsoft.insights/monitor"`. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings#diagnostic-setting-for-azure-sql-database and https://gist.github.com/rwaal/3d46c8b97a70750c2cbecf925b31fe92#file-azurediagsettings-resources-json-L49

Comment: it did not work for me somehow. I used the python libraries to configure the diagnostic settings

Comment: Did you progress any further with this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: I used python libraries, since I was not able to do it via ARM template